# Using all variables of a data.frame in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am very new to ml in R and am trying to simply add all variables from `X_train` to predict `y_train` in the model training. I am running into problem with them not being in the same `data.frame`. My code is as such:

```
logitmod <- glm(log_y_train ~ log_X_train, family = "binomial")
```

`log_y_train` is a factor of length 200386 and `log_X_train` is a `data.frame` of 174 variables and 200386 rows. It is for this reason I cannot simply type all column names.

However I get the following error:

> invalid type (list) for variable 'log_X_train'

I thought this was a dataframe but nonetheless tried `unlist()` when then told me lengths differed. Can anyone help to fix this issue to use both variables in the logit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Bind `log_y_train` and `log_X_train` into a `data.frame` so that you can use `" ~ ."` in a `formula` to represent all variables in `log_X_train`.

```
glm(log_y_train ~ ., family = binomial(), data = cbind(log_y_train, log_X_train))
```

---

#### Solution 2

Use `reformulate()` to create a `formula` with all variables in `log_X_train` as predictors and `log_y_train` as response. This one has no need to bind `log_y_train` and `log_X_train`.

```
glm(reformulate(names(log_X_train), "log_y_train"), family = binomial(), data = log_X_train)
```

Comment: I get this error: `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`

Comment: @geds133 I think there are some character or factor variables in `log_X_train` that just have single level. Please check.

Comment: @geds133 to reproduce the error, you can try `df <- iris[1:50, ] ; lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = df)`. This has the same error as yours. It's because the fifth column of my data `df` has a single value.

Comment: This is in fact the case. Fixing now, and will accept when managed to double check. Many thanks!